# what kind of floor tape can I put on my polyurethaned hardwood floors for spot re applying polyurethane.ng up

Tags: flooring, hardwood

I have some areas on my new hardwood floors where the polyurethane needs to be redone.  What kind of masking tape can be used to isolate the area that needs to be retouched without pulling up the polyurethane from the other floor boards.

Answer (score 1):

Painters tape should work just fine (the blue stuff)...but...I'm not sure you really need to tape it off. A light sanding of the area and you should be able to put the poly right over it to blend it all in.